# How to get value of JavaScript into HTML span?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a much simplified JavaScript method such as this:

```
function myfunction() {
     var i = 9;
}
```

Is there any way I can get the value of `i` into HTML such that when the web page with this method is called, the value `9` is displayed in a div or span element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi :D you can try the following using JQuery:

```
var i = 9;
$('#spanId').text(i);
```

or the classic old-fashion way:

```
var tmp= document.getElementById('spanId');
tmp.textContent = id;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: -1: Forcing your users to download a 31kb library for such a basic task is ridiculous. For people still on dial-up, this represents a good 5-10 seconds download. Also, [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) should be used instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Andrew, I edited my answer. And yes, while it is ridiculous to download a library for such a basic task, I was just showing another way to do it :).

Answer (score 5):

You can write `document.getElementById("some ID").innerHTML = i`

Answer (score 1):

You can use innerHTML to embed the i value in a div or span element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can assign an `id` to your `<div>` or `<span>` and set its [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) property to your value.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var content = myfunction();
  var tag = document.getElementById('displayVar');

  if(typeof tag.innerText == "undefined") {
    tag.textContent = content;
  } else {
    tag.innerText = content;
  }
}
```

Do not use `innerHTML` if you do not want the HTML code of your value to be parsed (or if you don't expect any HTML value).

And no, **you do not need a 31kb library to do that kind of work** (just in case there's a bunch of *"jQuery can do that!"* answers).

Note that you must also modify `myfunction()` so that it returns the current value. A simple `return i;` statement in the function will do the trick.

Comment: Note that innerText is a proprietary feature with rather weird behaviour for all but the simplest cases, and that textContent is much more widely implemented.

Answer (score 1):

myfunction() current does not return its value. However, if you want to get the value when the page is "called" (loaded) you can do this:

```
function myfunction() {
    var i = 9;
    return i;
}
```

And in the markup:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('id_of_your_div').innerHTML = myfunction()">
```

Please note that innerHTML has cross-browser issues, so you may want to use a library function such as jQuery's html() for reliable results.

Comment: -1: If you are not going to modify the HTML content of a tag, use `innerText`/`textContent`.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: innerText is completely unsupported in FF. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Comment: @George Commins: That's because FF uses the W3C standard [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) property instead. My answer reflects that.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: This simply strengthens the argument for a library. It is a waste of a (good) developer's time to write conditional code for every available browser.

Comment: @George Cummins: We are talking about a single if statement between `innerText` or `textContent`. Between that and permitting injection (there is no information about the datatype returned by the OP's function... It is *"much simplified"*, you can do the extra work for a simple if statement. That's the nature of vanilla-JS.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: If this is the only feature of a library that is needed, the overhead may indeed be too costly. But if a developer finds himself constantly writing common code, there is great value in using a library. Additionally, the assertion that "We are talking about a single if statement" may be correct today, but may not be correct the next time a new browser is released, or when the project requirements change ("Add support for IE 4!").

Comment: @George Cummins: Considering that browsers are moving towards standardization, I doubt that W3C's `textContent` is about to go away. In fact, starting in IE9, `textContent` is fully supported in all major browsers engines (Trident [IE], Gecko [FF], Webkit [Chrome, Safari], Presto [Opera]).

Comment: @Andrew Moore: The movement toward standardization is a great thing for developers, and I hope twenty years from now we can all look back on these troubles and laugh. But now, in the trenches, solutions must be found for the everyday problems. For now, the Javascript libraries often provide the standardization that the browsers lack.

Comment: @George Cummins: And as a fervent adopter of *[MooTools](http://mootools.net)* I agree with you. However, on this specific use case, a library is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var i = 9;
    return i;
}

$('myElement').innerHTML = myFunction();
```

HTML:

```
<span id="myElement"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use jQuery to simplify the syntax following are the three ways you can do that using jQuery,

1) $('span').text(i)

2) $('#someid').text(i) //someid =  value of id attribute of span tag.

3) $('.someclassname').text(i) //someclassname = class name for the span tag.

- Also using jQuery means forcing the users have to download addition jQuery lib when the page loads.  That might slow down the page depending on the connection speed of the users. You might want to consider that while selecting between jQuery and plain JavaScript

Comment: -1: Forcing your users to download a 31kb library for such a basic task is ridiculous. Also, before using jQuery, you should learn how vanilla JavaScript works. And since you are suggesting jQuery, you might as well to this the proper way and use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text).

Comment: Thanks Andrew! for pointing that out. I agree downloading the lib for such a task IS ridiculous. Obviously I missed a very important point.